# How is it possible to ensure a constant continuous update of location when iOS app is in the background?

Tags: ios, background, core-location, cllocationmanager

One requirement for our iOS app is to monitor location changes in the background. We have implemented "locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region", unfortunately we realised when testing the app thoroughly that it is too little precise to fulfil our needs.

We then used "locationManager startUpdatingLocation" to increase accuracy of location. In the foreground everything worked out quite good, this location precision is pretty much what we want.

Now the problem is when the app is in the background, the event "didUpdateLocations" is not called on regular basis. We observed this by looking into log file. What happens is pretty much always the same, the first 15 minutes the app updates the location regularly and then suddenly abruptly stops. After about a 5 minute break it carries on with updating the location for again about 15 minutes. And this continues on in the same way.

We probably made the mistake in the implementation in background handling.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;

bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

    if(rootViewController._selectedLocation == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"selected location is nil and app entered background");
        [rootViewController.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"selected location is not nil and app entered background");
        [rootViewController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

}];
```

This seem to be called about every 20 minutes and the location is updated again. What are we doing wrong and how can we get a regular location update without any interruptions? We tested this with iPhone 5 and also important to know it was stationary.

Comment: Do you ever call stopUpdatingLocation when in the background?  BTW, I believe you don't need to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` if you have the `location` key in your plist.

Comment: Also, what have you set for `activityType` property on [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)?  Did you set `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to NO?

Comment: Many thanks, you just solved it. I set the CllocationManager's pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to No. The app now updates the location on regular basis in the background. And yes, it looks like beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: is not necessary.Again thanks!

Comment: One interesting issue i must mention. I additionally tested the app without the solution above with the iPhone 4S and for some reason the location updates were never interrupted.

Comment: Did the 4S have ios 6?  That pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property is new to ios 6.

Comment: Would in some way make sense, but it is not the case the 4S which was tested runs currently on iOS 6.1.3

Comment: @BCI : Is your code working even if the app is killed or terminated ?

Comment: @BCI : Where will I have to write above code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your application plist file the following value:

**Required background modes**

It is an array telling the system what you app need when in background. For the position at item 0, you should inform the value:

**App registers for location updates**

In case of doubt, you can see in this link what I'm talking about: [iOS Multitasking: Background Location](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

Comment: thanks for the link and advice. The value "App registers for location updates" was added to the plist under "Required background modes". This does not seem to be the problem, the mistake is somewhere else. I will have a closer look at the link, you sent me.